# change the size of gridview's items using a custom font Android

Tags: android, gridview

I'm using a custom font to my GridView, which is applying perfectly but I wanna change the size of the text shown in the items.

I want to change the size of the texts of the GridView in both ways, programmatically and in how to do it in the XML file, knowing that I didn't know how to fill the GridView's items with text in the XML file without using programming.

**XML file**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/prenomgarc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:tag="big_screen"
    tools:context=".Activities.Menu.BBEnRoute.Prenom.PrenomGarcActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#91d0f0"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="@drawable/toolbar_garc"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:weightSum="1"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b_back"
                android:layout_width="19dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_back" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="470dp"
        android:layout_height="610dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/appbar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/prenom_back" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="470dp"
        android:layout_height="610dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/appbar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:paddingTop="15dp">

    </GridView>
```

**Java file**

```
public class PrenomGarcActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button b_back;
TextView a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,vv,w,x,y,z;
GridView gridview;

static final String[] names = new String[] {
        "Adam","Adel","Adil","Aissa","Amin","Amir","Assil", " ", " ",
        "Bachir","Badis","Bassim","Bilell"," "," ",
        "Chafik","Chahid","Chaker","Chams","Chawki"," ",
        "Djamel","Djalil"," ",
        "Fares"," "," ",
        "Ghani"," "," ",
        "Habib", "Hafid","Hakim","Halim","Hamid","Hani",
        "Idriss","Imed","Ismail",
        "Jabir"," "," ",
        "Kader","Kamel","Karim","Khaled","Khalill"," ",
        "Lotfi"," ", " ",
        "Mahboub","Mahfoud","Mahmoud","Malik","Mourad"," ",
        "Nabil","Nacer","Nadjib","Nassim","Nazim"," ",
        "Omar","Othmane","Oussama",
        "Rachid","Ramzi","Raouf","Rayan","Reda"," ",
        "Sabri","Salim","Sami",
        "Taoufik"," "," ",
        "Walid","Waiil","Wassim","Wafid"," "," ",
        "Yacine"," "," ",
        "Zahi","Zakaria","Zoubair",
        " "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "
        ," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ",
        " "," "," "};
static final String[] namesBigScreen = new String[] {
        "Adam","Adel","Adil","Aissa","Amin","Amir","Assil", " ",
        "Bachir","Badis","Bassim","Bilell",
        "Chafik","Chahid","Chaker","Chams","Chawki"," "," "," ",
        "Djamel","Djalil"," "," ",
        "Fares"," "," "," ",
        "Ghani"," "," "," ",
        "Habib", "Hafid","Hakim","Halim","Hamid","Hani"," "," ",
        "Idriss","Imed","Ismail"," ",
        "Jabir"," "," "," ",
        "Kader","Kamel","Karim","Khaled","Khalill"," "," "," ",
        "Lotfi"," ", " ", " ",
        "Mahboub","Mahfoud","Mahmoud","Malik","Mourad"," ", " ", " ",
        "Nabil","Nacer","Nadjib","Nassim","Nazim"," ", " ", " ",
        "Omar","Othmane","Oussama", " ",
        "Rachid","Ramzi","Raouf","Rayan","Reda"," ", " ", " ",
        "Sabri","Salim","Sami", " ",
        "Taoufik"," "," ", " ",
        "Walid","Waiil","Wassim","Wafid",
        "Yacine"," "," ", " ",
        "Zahi","Zakaria","Zoubair", " ",};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_prenom_garc);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    b_back  =(Button) findViewById(R.id.b_back);
    b_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PrenomGarcActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });



    gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

    Typeface custom_font= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),  "fonts/tgr.otf");

    if(findViewById(R.id.prenomgarc).getTag().equals("med_screen")) {
        GridAdapter adapter = new GridAdapter(this, names, custom_font);

        gridview.setAdapter(adapter);

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                if (!names[position].equals(" ")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(PrenomGarcActivity.this, PrenomSpecActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("nom", names[position]);
                    intent.putExtra("sexe", "g");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }else{
        GridAdapter adapter = new GridAdapter(this, namesBigScreen, custom_font);

        gridview.setAdapter(adapter);

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                if (!namesBigScreen[position].equals(" ")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(PrenomGarcActivity.this, PrenomSpecActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("nom", namesBigScreen[position]);
                    intent.putExtra("sexe", "g");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }


}

private int getscroll(String s){
    for (int i = 0; i <names.length; i++){
        if (names[i].substring(0,1).toLowerCase().equals(s))
            return i;
    }
    return 100;
}
}
```

Comment: The `GridAdapter` class is what would be of interest.It will look something like [this](https://github.com/delaroy/AndroidTeachers/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/delaroystudios/teacherassistant/gridAdapter.java). The [`getView()`](https://github.com/delaroy/AndroidTeachers/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/delaroystudios/teacherassistant/gridAdapter.java#L64) method should have a reference to your `TextView`s.

Comment: this didn't help. I can't find anyway to refer to the items and change their size.